# Is there a possible way to check for second parentheses in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm working on a Javascript challenge. The challenge is the code below in which you add the numbers provided together:

```
function addTogether() {
//I left this blank because I'm focused on checking for the second parentheses
}
```

However, if you tried to pass this `addTogether(5)(7)` to the `function addTogether()`, it would be difficult to get the second parentheses.

However, you can get both parentheses if you write this code:

```
function addTogether() {
  //get first parenteses
  let first = arguments;
  //get second parentheses
  let second = function() {
    return arguments;
  };
}
```

But my question is how do you check if there's a second parentheses? Because I'm passing other data such as `addTogether(2,3)`. In other words, I might be passing some with one parentheses and another with two parentheses to the `function addTogether()`

Comment: Unless you pass the arguments as a string, you cannot do this because javascript does not provide macros support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check, unless you're parsing the source code, but your function can optionally accept second argument and if it's provided return the sum, otherwise return a function

```js
const addTogether = (a, opt) => opt ? a + opt : b => a + b

console.log("addTogether(1,3) => ", addTogether(1,3))

console.log("addTogether(4)(6) => ", addTogether(4)(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementation using function that coerces to number.
Using reduce to calculate sums.  Overriding @@toPrimitive to create function that coerces to value of add.  Recursive call to generate recursively chainable callable number coercable functions.

Check [ECMAScript specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-type-conversion) if you want to customize behavior further. You will need to understand the conversion path.

```js
function sum(...args) {
  const first = args.reduce((sum,x)=>sum+x,0)

  const second = function(...args) {return sum(first, ...args)}
  second[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function(){return first}
  return second
}
console.log(
1+sum(1)(2)+sum(1)+sum(3),
sum(1,1,2) (1,3)(0)(0)+sum(0,-1,1,0),
sum(1)(1)(2)(1)(3)(0)(0)(-1,1)(0)+sum()
)
```